# models MIMIC, predicted probabilities?

Tags: predictive-models, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I am investigating MIMIC (Multiple Indicators Multiple Causes) models since with them I can do regressions, including factors (made up of several items), and the observed variables (glycemia, cholesterol, blood pressure, etc.)

The issue is that I only get the probit coefficients, which beyond the sign and magnitude, do not offer me much more for interpretation.

My question is if there is no possibility to add a probability study with some command. For example, Stata offers, after performing the probit regression, with the "margins" or "mfx" command, for example.

I was looking at a forum where Muthem points out that there would be something like this in MPlus, but I couldn't find it either.
Do you know any way in R Lavaan or MPlus?

---

Good morning Jeremy, thanks for responding.
I go point by point:

1. By probability study I understand, for example, what STATA does with Probit coefficients. I copy an example about the probability of working or not working, of a single (married=0) or married (married=1) woman, adjusting for age and level of education.

```r
    margins, at (married=(0 1)) atmeans vsquish
    
    Adjusted predictions             Number of obs   =         30
    Model VCE    : OIM
    
    Expression   : Pr(work), predict()
    1._at        : married          =           0
                   education      =    11.83333 (mean)
                   age            =    41.33333 (mean)
    2._at        : married          =           1
                   education       =    11.83333 (mean)
                   age             =    41.33333 (mean)
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 |            Delta-method
                 |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
    -------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             _at |
              1  |   .8993173   .0944451     9.52   0.000     .7142083    1.084426
              2  |   .4300886   .1344599     3.20   0.001     .1665521    .6936251
```

2. As I understand it, MIMIC (Multiple Indicators, Multiple Causes) models work with probit coefficients, when the dependent variable is ordinal.
3. https://www.statmodel.com/discussion/messages/11/266.html?1601339295

Linda K. Muthen posted on Tuesday, November 16, 2004 - 10:19 am
“See Technical Appendix 1 for a description of how to calculate probabilities from a probit regression coefficient.”

---

I very much appreciate your help.
I don't quite understand how I should do it to estimate the probability, for example, of the married variable. I'll copy the syntax and the run model from RStudio:

```r
library(lavaan)
modeloTrabajo <- 'asertividad = ~ var7 + var8                                                            
caracter =~ x64 + x65 + x66 + x67
trabajo ~ casada + escola + edad + caracter + asertividad'
fit <- sem(modeloTrabajo, data = datosTrabajo, ordered=TRUE, estimator="wlsmv")
summary(fit, rsquare=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, fit.measures=TRUE)


lavaan 0.6.17 ended normally after 29 iterations

  Estimator                                       DWLS
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        34

  Number of observations                           113

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Scaled
  Test Statistic                                42.929      46.886
  Degrees of freedom                                30          30
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.059       0.026
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.143
  Shift parameter                                            9.317
    simple second-order correction                                

Model Test Baseline Model:

  Test statistic                               848.557     499.103
  Degrees of freedom                                21          21
  P-value                                        0.000       0.000
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.731

User Model versus Baseline Model:

  Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.984       0.965
  Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.989       0.975
                                                                  
  Robust Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                            NA
  Robust Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                               NA

Root Mean Square Error of Approximation:

  RMSEA                                          0.062       0.071
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower         0.000       0.025
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper         0.101       0.108
  P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.050                    0.297       0.184
  P-value H_0: RMSEA >= 0.080                    0.250       0.374
                                                                  
  Robust RMSEA                                                  NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - lower                        NA
  90 Percent confidence interval - upper                        NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA <= 0.050                            NA
  P-value H_0: Robust RMSEA >= 0.080                            NA

Standardized Root Mean Square Residual:

  SRMR                                           0.056       0.056

Parameter Estimates:

  Parameterization                               Delta
  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  asertividad =~                                                        
    var7              1.000                               0.929    0.929
    var8              0.894    0.066   13.582    0.000    0.831    0.831
  caracter =~                                                           
    x64               1.000                               0.744    0.744
    x65               0.990    0.099   10.006    0.000    0.737    0.737
    x66              -0.841    0.114   -7.381    0.000   -0.626   -0.626
    x67               1.207    0.108   11.140    0.000    0.898    0.898


Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  trabajo ~                                                             
    casada           -1.470    0.313   -4.701    0.000   -1.470   -0.461
    escola            0.387    0.107    3.607    0.000    0.387    0.542
    edad             -0.010    0.016   -0.646    0.518   -0.010   -0.079
    caracter          0.119    0.155    0.766    0.444    0.088    0.055
    asertividad       0.923    0.113    8.183    0.000    0.858    0.538

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  asertividad ~~                                                        
    caracter         -0.043    0.075   -0.575    0.565   -0.062   -0.062

Thresholds:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
    var7|t1          -0.093    0.926   -0.100    0.920   -0.093   -0.093
    var7|t2           0.636    0.926    0.687    0.492    0.636    0.636
    var7|t3           1.867    0.914    2.044    0.041    1.867    1.867
    var8|t1           0.663    0.838    0.791    0.429    0.663    0.663
    var8|t2           1.195    0.850    1.405    0.160    1.195    1.195
    var8|t3           1.926    0.864    2.229    0.026    1.926    1.926
    x64|t1           -2.043    0.790   -2.586    0.010   -2.043   -2.043
    x64|t2           -0.696    0.798   -0.872    0.383   -0.696   -0.696
    x64|t3           -0.005    0.812   -0.006    0.995   -0.005   -0.005
    x64|t4            0.599    0.841    0.712    0.477    0.599    0.599
    x65|t1           -2.035    0.983   -2.069    0.039   -2.035   -2.035
    x65|t2           -0.876    0.965   -0.908    0.364   -0.876   -0.876
    x65|t3           -0.493    0.974   -0.506    0.613   -0.493   -0.493
    x65|t4            0.520    1.060    0.490    0.624    0.520    0.520
    x66|t1           -1.526    1.069   -1.428    0.153   -1.526   -1.526
    x66|t2           -0.682    0.948   -0.719    0.472   -0.682   -0.682
    x66|t3            0.387    0.916    0.422    0.673    0.387    0.387
    x66|t4            1.007    0.916    1.100    0.271    1.007    1.007
    x67|t1           -1.210    0.873   -1.386    0.166   -1.210   -1.210
    x67|t2            0.137    0.871    0.158    0.875    0.137    0.137
    x67|t3            0.562    0.864    0.650    0.516    0.562    0.562
    trabajo|t1        2.863    1.563    1.832    0.067    2.863    1.796

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
   .var7              0.137                               0.137    0.137
   .var8              0.310                               0.310    0.310
   .x64               0.446                               0.446    0.446
   .x65               0.457                               0.457    0.457
   .x66               0.608                               0.608    0.608
   .x67               0.194                               0.194    0.194
   .trabajo           0.266                               0.266    0.105
    asertividad       0.863    0.104    8.277    0.000    1.000    1.000
    caracter          0.554    0.090    6.126    0.000    1.000    1.000

R-Square:
                   Estimate
    var7              0.863
    var8              0.690
    x64               0.554
    x65               0.543
    x66               0.392
    x67               0.806
    trabajo           0.895
```

Comment: What do you mean by a probability study? Why are there probit coefficients? Can you point to the discussion where Muthen said this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly weird thing to want to do, because you're interested in the predicted level of a categorical variable, given the level of a factor. But the level of the factor is determined by the categorical variable.

I believe you can do this with non-linear constraints.

You can create new parameters in Lavaan using the := operator. These parameters will have a standard error (and hence a CI).

When I do something new in SEM, I like to do it in something I understand better first. So let's use the cars dataset and do a regression, then predict the speed of the first car (which has dist = 2).

```
data(cars)

fit_lm_cars <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
summary(fit_lm_cars)
predict(fit_lm_cars, se.fit = TRUE)
```

This gives me a predicted value of 8.615 with SE = 0.844.

Let's try the same thing in SEM, using a new parameter.

```
data(cars)

fit_lm_cars <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
summary(fit_lm_cars)
predict(fit_lm_cars, se.fit = TRUE)
```

The output contains:

```
Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    pred_2            8.615    0.827   10.412    0.000
```

Cool. The approach seems to work.

Now let's expand it to a factor model. You didn't post a reproducible example, so I'm going to use a lavaan example. I'll create a predicted value of x2 for a latent variable value of 0, 1 and -1.

```
library(lavaan)
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + lambda_2_1 * x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 
              x1 ~ int_1 * 1
              visual ~~ 1 * visual
  # create new params              
  pred_visual_0 := int_1 + 0 * lambda_2_1
  pred_visual_1 := int_1 + 1 * lambda_2_1
  pred_visual_neg_1 := int_1 + -1 * lambda_2_1
  '

fit.HS.ortho <- cfa(HS.model, 
                    data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
                    orthogonal = TRUE, meanstructure = TRUE)
summary(fit.HS.ortho)
```

And there are your parameters:

```
Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    pred_visual_0     4.936    0.072   68.914    0.000
    pred_visual_1     5.467    0.107   51.179    0.000
    pred_visl_ng_1    4.404    0.107   41.228    0.000
```

I think that Mplus has a similar function for non-linear constraints.

I've heard the margins command in Stata is very good at giving you *almost* what you want, and what you *think* you want, so I never use it. But I would consider first reproducing your margins result in Lavaan or Mplus to make sure you are doing the same thing.  I've (almost) never used the sem command in Stata, so I don't know about that.